# Fetching one document from firebase (Vue)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch a specific document from firebase, based on my route params (id) where I'm using the auto-generated firebase ID to retrieve the document.

However, nothing no data is being returned.

Using the when() method, I would like to retrieve a specific document with an auto-generated ID that matches my query...I'm using ("id", "==", $this.route.params.id)... is "id" the right syntax when referring to the auto-generated ID?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the simple database I have set up...]

I'm going to manipulate UI later, for now, I simply have this in the template...

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>{{ huddle.goal }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ huddle.headline }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ huddle.body }}</h1>
 </div>
</template>
```

and then I have this in my script...

```
<script>
import db from "./firebaseInit"
export default {
  name: "HuddleSpace",
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  watch: {
    "$route": "fetchData"
  },
  methods: {  
    fetchData() {
      db.collection("huddle").where("id", "==", 
       this.$route.params.id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
         const huddle = {
            goal: doc.data().goal,
            headline: doc.data().headline,
            body: doc.data().body
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I'm going off of the Vue Router docs for "data fetching after navigation" / firebase docs for getting data / a few videos on youtube, so I'm not sure that the logic makes sense.

Comment: It's best to always ask a specific question or explain what problem are you running into with your code. You should take a closer look though what you are doing with the response doc you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make a query,
The id you deal with is the document id, so to get it use =>

```
db.collection('huddle').doc(this.$route.params.id)
.get().then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) return;
    let data = snapshot.data() // 
    // continue your code
});
```

// where("id", "==", this.$route.params.id) =>This make a query to get documents which have field name (id) with specified value ($this.route.params.id)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that your `huddle` object is not included in the `data` object and therefore it is not added to "Vue’s reactivity system". See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods for more detail.

You should do as follows:

```
<script>
import db from "./firebaseInit"
export default {
  name: "HuddleSpace",
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      huddle: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  watch: {
    "$route": "fetchData"
  },
  methods: {  
    fetchData() {
      db.collection("huddle").where("id", "==", 
       this.$route.params.id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
         this.huddle = {
            goal: doc.data().goal,
            headline: doc.data().headline,
            body: doc.data().body
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Renaud. The empty object was included in the original code before I made this post...either way, I tried copy and pasting your code, still with no data being retrieved. Other vue components have retrieved data from firebase without issue, and are also rendering in the router-view. Since I don't fully understand the logic of the call to firebase, I thought the problem may lie there...

Comment: @AdrianCaballero Hi, I've tried the code of my answer before posting it and it works. What happens if you do `console.log(this.$route.params.id);`at the begining of `fetchData()`? Do you get the correct id?

Comment: Very strange. I really appreciate you helping me with this. I just console.loged this.$route.params.id and the correct id is logging to the console, but still nothing rendering where I have established my route-view.

Comment: @AdrianCaballero Ok, now can you pls check the size of the `querySnapshot` with `...get().then(querySnapshot => {console.log(querySnapshot.size); ....})` and verifying it is > 0

Comment: It is currently logging 0. What does this mean?

Comment: It means that your query returns 0 result. This is why you don’t see any result. What is the data type of the id field? Can you add to your question some detail’about your Firestore data model?

Comment: I've added a bit to my question above, I hope this clarifies some of your questions. The previous screen in my web app is a table of "huddles"...the user clicks on one of the items on the table which generates this page...which is successfully populating the auto-gen ID to the URL, but doesn't seem to be matching when I call to retrieve the data again from firebase. Is "id" the right syntax when referring to the auto-gen id? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, the use of `where()` in your question (and in my answer) is correct. There is something that does not work since you get 0 result to your query, but it is difficult to find it! You should use my code and verify at each line that you get what is expected. Also it would be good that you post a print screen of your Firestore database.

Comment: No error message in the console? No security rules that would prevent the data fetch?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my simple setup on firebase...and I did get this error one time, but I'm not getting it anymore "net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200"